# How do I level up a TF2 character?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was looking at some achievement items in TF2, and I found that for a hat, you have to 'level up' your character. What does that mean?

Comment: Could you say the name of the achievement that said that? Or the name of the item?

Answer (score 7):

### I think you may have  meant "Achievement Milestones".

*Team Fortress 2 does not have character levels. You could either be confusing between a **Steam Profile Level**, **Strange Item Levels** or **Achievement Milestones**.*

#### Achievement Milestones

Achievement milestones are achievements that you get when you have completed a certain number of achievements in a achievement set (series of achievements for ie. a certain class or event).

As you complete an achievement milestone for a class, you are granted an achievement item at each milestone, or as a reward for completing certain achievements (list below, see wiki for more info)

As for hats:
*See https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Achievement_items#Hats*

There are several hats you can earn through achievements:

1. **Ghostly Gibus** - Earn the Ghastly Gibus Grab achievement.
2. **Mildly Disturbing Halloween Mask** - Earn the Candy Coroner achievement.
3. **Horseless Headless Horsemann's Head** - Earn the Sleepy Holl0WND achievement.
4. **Frontline Field Recorder** - Earn the Local Cinema Star achievement.
5. **MONOCULUS!** - Earn the Optical Defusion achievement.
6. **Full Head of Steam** - Complete 7 achievements in the Foundry Pack. *(To trigger the Foundry Milestone achievement)*
7. **Gentle Munitionne of Leisue** - Complete 7 achievements in the Doomsday pack. *(To trigger the Doomsday Milestone achievement)*
8. **Skull Island Topper** - Earn the A Lovely Vacation Spot achievement.

#### Steam Profile Level

*Not related to Team Fortress 2 in any way*

A steam level is your Steam profile level, which can be increased by:

- Buying more games
- Crafting Badges
- Participating in events

#### Strange Items

*These things you can level up based on the number of kills or times used successfully.*

You can level up items with a strange quality (orange name) by killing/using successfully (ie. With Mad Milk, it's the # of enemies soaked using that item). As you reach milestones, its prefix will change from **Strange** to others, depending on the rank number (and its threshold).

See https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange#Ranks for more information.

Comment: This answer does not seem 'correct', or at least there is a lot of unneeded/unrequested/noisy information. The question mentions a hat from an achievement and only about 1/3 of your answer is about hats! Maybe wait until the question is edited/corrected with specifics before just providing a shotgun blast of information in a hope to answer the question.

Comment: @ColinD You're assuming the question *will* be updated, which I doubt will actually happen.

Comment: @Powerlord it is never updated, it will likely get closed (I see 2 closevotes already). Making answers on it meaningless anyway.

Comment: @ColinD After thinking about it, I think I figured out which hats they were referring to.

Comment: I had no idea what the question was asking about.. The OP didn't reply and thus because TF2 doesn't have an XP system, I just stated anything that was level-related (apart from item levels) or hat-related. And I think http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191492/75275 (scroll down/up) seems to know what the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

The only hats in TF2 that require you to level a character are the [Flamingo Kid](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Flamingo_Kid) and [Triclops](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Triclops) hats.

However, the leveling in question has to be done in the game [Super Monday Night Combat](http://store.steampowered.com/app/104700/), **not** Team Fortress 2.

Specifically, Flamingo Kid requires you to reach Level 5 in SMNC, while Triclops requires you to reach level 20 in SMNC.

Incidentally, the level is account-wide in SMNC and can be gotten with any combination of characters.  You're awarded experience after every match, although winning a match awards you more XP than losing a match.

Comment: Don't forget to include these are non-TF2 achievement items, just like the Spiral Sallet (Reach the first Clockworks Terminal *in Spiral Knights*).

Comment: I totally forgot that Strange hats were a thing when I wrote this.  These hats will have their prefixes change as you get kills until you eventually have a "Hale's Own" hat.  However, this is purely cosmetic, just like Strange weapons are.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could be talking about weapon levels; for example, the Eyelander is a level 5 sword, and the Mantreads are level 10 boots. Levels are purely cosmetic and for "bling", like unusual hats.You do not need to "level up" or anything to equip these weapons.